# Powershell change timestamp from file name

Tags: powershell

Is there a way to use powershell to change the timestamp on a group of files?
Example I have a file

```
2017-05-26-23-45-37.000_4043.JPG
```

I would like to extract the date `2017-05-26` and time `23-45-37` and change the modified time stamp to match the filename.

And apply this process in a loop to each *.JPG* file in the folder.

Comment: What have you tried so far? straight forward ans is-- yes possible

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/924365/changing-last-modified-date-or-time-via-powershell

Answer (score 2):

```
Get-ChildItem 2017-[01][0-9]-[0-3][0-9]-[0-2][0-9]-[0-5][0-9]-[0-5][0-9].*.JPG | 
ForEach-Object {
    $strtime = $_.Name.Split('.')[0]
    $fdate = [datetime]::ParseExact($strtime,”yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm-ss”,$null)
    $_.LastWriteTime = $fDate
}
```

---

The same as a one liner:

```
GCI 2017-[01][0-9]-[0-3][0-9]-[0-2][0-9]-[0-5][0-9]-[0-5][0-9].*.JPG|%{$_.LastWriteTime=[datetime]::ParseExact($_.Name.Split('.')[0],”yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm-ss”,$null)}
```